# Copy column values from multiple table and insert into 3rd table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, laravel-5

I wish to populate `'ShippingOrder' with 'Contains.ISBN', 'Contains.number', 'Stocks.warehouseCode'` and for username, I am getting it from a join between `'Contains.basketID' = 'ShoppingBasket.basketID'`

I have this working for me in mysql-

```
INSERT INTO ShippingOrder (SELECT DISTINCT co.ISBN, s.warehouseCode, sb.username, co.number FROM Contains co INNER JOIN Stocks s INNER JOIN ShoppingBasket sb ON co.ISBN = s.ISBN AND sb.basketID=co.basketID AND co.basketID='".$basketID."' GROUP BY co.ISBN)

TABLE `ShippingOrder` (
  `ISBN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouseCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TABLE `Contains` (
  `ISBN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `basketID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TABLE `Stocks` (
  `ISBN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouseCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TABLE `ShoppingBasket` (
  `basketID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I don't understand how I can execute this in Laravel 5+.
I can run simple queries but I have no clue how to run the one mentioned above.
Thank you.[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdkmq.jpg)

Comment: The above is a simple query as well. If the question is how to express the above query with laravel objects, then my answer is: don't waste your time on it, just run a raw query.

Comment: The query works fine in CodeIgniter or inside PhpMyAdmin. However, It is not inserting from inside Laravel. Is this correct? $result = DB::raw("INSERT INTO shippingorder (SELECT DISTINCT co.ISBN, s.warehouseCode, sb.username, co.number FROM Contains co INNER JOIN Stocks s INNER JOIN ShoppingBasket sb ON co.ISBN = s.ISBN AND sb.basketID=co.basketID AND co.basketID='1' GROUP BY co.ISBN)");

Answer (score 0):

You could try either formatting the output

So that if you returned the result from the first query, instead of the INSERT INTO straight away you could

```
DB::table('ShippingOrder')->insert(
    ['ISBN' => '123', 'warehouseCode' => 1, 'username' => 'bob', 'number' => 4]
);
```

So if you had the results as array:

```
DB::table('ShippingOrder')->insert(
    $rows
);
```

OR do it all straight in a raw query

```
DB::raw('INSERT INTO ShippingOrder ...'); // plus rest of query
```

So you would be skipping some of the Laravel offering but still possible.

Comment: The query works fine in CodeIgniter or inside PhpMyAdmin. However, It is not inserting from inside Laravel. Is this correct? $result = DB::raw("INSERT INTO shippingorder (SELECT DISTINCT co.ISBN, s.warehouseCode, sb.username, co.number FROM Contains co INNER JOIN Stocks s INNER JOIN ShoppingBasket sb ON co.ISBN = s.ISBN AND sb.basketID=co.basketID AND co.basketID='1' GROUP BY co.ISBN)");